# Using PHP to recursively replace HTML elements and their values for sanitization

Tags: php, html, xpath, tinymce, domdocument

I am working ona project that involves HTML input from users using TinyMCE. At this point, the only way I can think of validating/sanitizing the HTML data is to use DomDocument in PHP and a whitelist of allowed HTML tags.

So using DomDocument, I first loop through all the tags, looking only for the specific tags that are allowed (the 'whitelist'), and replace them with new elements and their allowed attributes, obviously copying the values from the old tags entered by the user.

This way, not only can I control the tags that are entered by the user, but their attributes as well and there will hopefully be no 'leaks.'

So far, I have managed to use a class I found on PHP.net to loop through the body of this HTMLinput:

```
class ArrayNode{
public $nodeName, $nodeValue;
}

function getChildNodeElements( $domNode ){
    $nodes = array();
    for( $i=0; $i < $domNode->childNodes->length; $i++){
        $cn = $domNode->childNodes->item($i);
        if( $cn->nodeType == 1){
        $nodes[] = $cn;
        }
    }
       return $nodes;
}

function getArrayNodes( $domDoc ){
$res = array();

for( $i=0; $i < $domDoc->childNodes->length; $i++){
$cn = $domDoc->childNodes->item($i);
    # The first is the root tag...
if( $cn->nodeType == 1){
    # But we want it's childNodes.
    $sub_cn = getChildNodeElements( $cn);
    # Found the tagName:
    $baseItemTagName = $sub_cn[0]->nodeName;
    break;
    }
}

$dnl = $domDoc->getElementsByTagName( $baseItemTagName);

for( $i=0; $i< $dnl->length; $i++){
    $arrayNode = new ArrayNode();

    # Summary
    $arrayNode->nodeName = $dnl->item($i)->nodeName;
    $arrayNode->nodeValue = $dnl->item($i)->nodeValue;

    # Child Nodes
    $cn = $dnl->item($i)->childNodes;
    for( $k=0; $k<$cn->length; $k++){
    if( $cn->item($k)->nodeName == "#text" && trim($cn->item($k)->nodeValue) == "") continue;
    $arrayNode->{$cn->item($k)->nodeName} = $cn->item($k)->nodeValue;
    }

    # Attributes
    $attr = $dnl->item($i)->attributes;
    for( $k=0; $k < $attr->length; $k++){
    if(! is_null($attr)){
        if( $attr->item($k)->nodeName == "#text" && trim($attr->item($k)->nodeValue) == "") continue;
        $arrayNode->{$attr->item($k)->nodeName} = $attr->item($k)->nodeValue;
    }
    }

    $res[] = $arrayNode;
}

return $res;
}
```

Is this approach the right way for sanitizing HTML input entered using TinyMCE? How does Stackoverflow deal with this? Also, how does one go about replacing elements recursively inside such HTML so that the positions of the tag elements remains unchanged?

Any help with this would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Be sure to use `htmlentities()` when saving into the database. Also, http://htmlpurifier.org/ is a nice option for sanitizing html.

Comment: Sure, and thanks @Hisamu. Actually, htmlentities should be used on data when it is on its way out of the database. Unless of course you are using alternative strategies of saving duplicate data to deal with user edits etc. Anyway, what I am looking for is a way to parse this HTML recursively, that is, respecting tag elements and their positions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are ready-to-use classes to sanitize HTML in PHP (but cannot tell you any recommendations). Otherwise: use an expression like `//*[not(local-name(.) = 'h1' or local-name(.) = 'h2')]` to select all nodes you do not want to allow and remove them. No need for renaming back and forth...